# Django aggregate and Distinct together

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset

I have to achieve the following.

```
class rooms(models.Model):
    uniqueKey = models.IntegerField() #this can have same value multiple times
    sellingPrice = models.IntegerField()
```

My query looks like something below

```
rooms.objects.all().distinct('uniquekey').aggregate(Sum('sellingPrice'))
```

I want to sum Selling price for all distinct uniquekeys.Above query Gives Following error.

```
NotImplementedError("aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.")
```

[image]

**OutPut of above image should be:**

```
{'sellingPrice__sum':150}
```

Please Help Me.

Comment: Exactly what should happen if the key is in the queryset twice or more? Take the minimum? The maximum?

Comment: Sum of selling price for distinct  uniqueKey should be output

Comment: So for each unique key, you want a "result record"?

Comment: No, I want to sum selling price. output in Django should be {'sellingPrice__sum':45}

Comment: so if two `rooms` occur with the *same* `uniqueKey`, then *which* of the `sellingPrice`s do you use for that `uniqueKey`?

Comment: First one default order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241584/discussion-between-piyush-bali-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: there is no default order: a database can return items in any possible order, making the result non-deterministic.

Comment: It's okay because the selling price is the same for the same `uniqueKey` you can think of it as repeated rows with different primary keys.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Please check image i have attached i think that will make your doubts clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first annotate with the `Min` `sellingPrice` (or another tie breaker) for each `uniqueKey`, and then aggregate, so:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Sum

rooms.objects.values('uniquekey').annotate(
    min=Min('sellingPrice')
).aggregate(
    sellingPrice__sum=Sum('min')
)
```